# value of content type of drupal visible in sugarcrm

Tags: drupal-7, sugarcrm, drupal-webform

**what I want** : value of content type of drupal visible in sugarcrm.

**What I have Done**:- I have created a content type and mange their field, for that I use module webform2sugar.

**getting problem** :- with the help of above module  when I create a field in webform  then data is visible in lead of sugarcrm  and the field of content type is not visible in sugarcrm

also I need the value in account of sugarcrm not in lead.

I have wasted lots of time but not getting any result.

Answer (score 0):

webform2sugar is use to capture a lead in sugarcrm. its only capture data only not the field, means if you create a field movie_name in drupal webform, which is not visible in sugarcrm lead edit or detail view.

webform2sugar module is use to capture only lead not for account. for account you use sugar soap and call set_entry function.

Comment: hi rupesh  what I have to do for getting the field value in sugarcrm.